# Passing concatenated JavaScript string into JQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pass a concatenated JavaScript string into a JQuery variable?

Example:

HTML:

```
<input id="Faculty1input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty2input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty3input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty4input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty5input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty6input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty7input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty8input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty9input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty10input" style="width:100%" />
```

JS:

```
for(x=1;x<=10;x++){
    var str2 = 'Faculty';
    var str3 = x; 
    var str4 = 'input';
    var input = str2.concat(str3,str4);

    if( $.trim( $("#" + input).val() ) == ''){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: why not, jquery is javascript

Comment: this syntax isn't working ... do you have a solution/suggestion?

Comment: @faalbane :can you post your complete code in the question?

Comment: So where does string `'FacultyNotes'` come from? Doesn't match anything in the html

Comment: just updated ... I have multiple HTML elements ... the string is matching in my test code ...

Comment: Well don't post mismatching code or people will focus on the obvious

Comment: you can't have multiple id's . here is some basic example http://jsbin.com/nogoyi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @itsgoingdown the ID's are unique

Comment: these are all unique elements ...

Comment: you'll have to accomplish this with classes

Comment: The basics of your selector [works fine here](https://jsfiddle.net/ds4nj00g/1). What is the specific problem? Is this code being used inside `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not explicitly answering your question according to the title, but it would be easier/better you were using classes for this, or, if you are doing this for all inputs on the page, just use `$('input').each()`:

```js
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
        document.write('foo<br>')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Faculty1input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty2input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty3input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty4input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty5input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty6input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty7input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty8input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty9input" style="width:100%" />
<input id="Faculty10input" style="width:100%" />
```

Or with a class:

```js
$('.faculty').each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
     document.write('foo<br>')
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Faculty1input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty2input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty3input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty4input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty5input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty6input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty7input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty8input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty9input"  class="faculty" style="width:100%" />
    <input id="Faculty10input" class="faculty"  style="width:100%" />
```